# scrollviewBeginDragging for TableView in ios not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a **Main View controller** with `two tabs` each one is a ***container view***. Here **First Tab** is a **Scroll View** and **Second Tab** is a **table view**. My goal is to achieve the `selected tab to be scrolled upside` when it is being scrolled. I achieved this action in the Main view controller for the First Tab [Scroll View] by using `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging` but when i try to implement this for my second Tab in the same main view controller. My second Tab [Table view] is scrolling to top but `didselectmethod` of the second Tab is **not working**. how to fix this issue? Is there any way to access the delegate of tableview from one view controller to the another [Like using its delegate].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom delegate for second tab[table view] and call the delegate function in the Main View controller. In main view controller call the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method in the delegate function.